# hyperledger fabric working use case in java

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am a beginner in Hyperledger, so need your help here;
as I want to create a blockchain with Hyperledger Fabric using java. And is their any working use case related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't use Java to write chaincode yet. You can deploy chaincode written in go and write client using Java sdk. You can check out hyperledger composer.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java

Answer (score 0):

You can check it here, there're some chaincode example write in java.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release/examples/chaincode/java

***chaincode_example02*** is a money transfer example that is used most often.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW this (now outdated) guide from IBM provides instructions how to run chaincode written in Java on hyperledger-fabric. However, following it as-is didn't not work for me, possibly can make it work with some effort

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-chaincode-for-java-developers/index.html